# Light fixture with confusing wires

Tags: light-fixture

[image]I bought new light from eBay .. light comes with red,white and black wires as attached in pic ..

I have no clue how to connect it to box with white,copper and black wires.

Comment: Just seeing one end of the wires don't let us know enough.  ebay electrical devices are probably not the most trust worthy or safe(not giving instructions is a good giveaway).  Might not even be be legal to connect and/or your insurance will have a very good reason to keep all your money.  If you can, show us how the wires are connected to the fixture.

Comment: Take a picture of the instructions/wiring diagrams and include them in your question.

Comment: @Ruskes those are crimp connectors

Comment: @Ruskesr two different wires going in ... three crimp marks in the plastic shell

Comment: Aren't there any wires that don't end in crimp connectors?

Comment: Either the fixture is UL Listed or it isn't.  (CE is not a valid listing agency).  The vast majority of electrical on eBay is unsafe cheap garbage that doesn't meet our safety standards.  They don't even share the savings with you most of the time, so you're paying domestic prices for stuff they're buying for less than 10% on alibaba.   This all day https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCTiU2ZHVwI except that $2 lights are *dangerous*.